# jQuery dynamic table live click plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, html-table

I'm trying to write jquery-plugin for table.

I have 2 dynamic tables from server:

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.smplPlugin = function() {
      return this.each(function() {  
        $this = $(this);
        $this.find("td").live('click', function() {
          alert($this.attr('id') +" "+ $(this).parent().attr('id'));
        });
      });
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#first_column").smplPlugin ();
       $("#second_column").smplPlugin ();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first_column">
  <table>
    <tr id="f1">
      <td class="select">some text</td>
      <td class="name">some name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="f2">
<!--
      ....
      more same rows
      ....
-->
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="second_column">
  <table>
    <tr id="s1">
      <td class="select">some text</td>
      <td class="name">some name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="s2">
<!--
      ....
      more same rows with differents id's
      ....
-->
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

then I want to add click event on `<td>`.

when I click on `<td>` on first or on second table, I always get the same, last object id, it's: second_column, but different first or second rows id's

click on [first column][tr id=f1][td class=name] output second_class f1

click on [second column][tr id=s2][td class=select] output second_class s2

and so on.
Any ideas?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .live() is deprecated for .on()  See http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

Your line `$this = $(this);` must be `var $this = $(this);`.

The former creates a global variable called `$this` and assigns a new value/reference in each iteration of your each-loop – using the variable thus always points to the last iterated element. The latter code creates a variable within the closure of your loop body – thus giving each click-handler a reference to its row.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.smplPlugin = function() {
    $("td",this).live('click', function() {
      alert($(this).parent().attr('id') +" "+ $(this).parents('div').attr('id'));          
     });
  };
})(jQuery);
```